# mongoose.Schema only populating contents of one array

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose, postman

I am trying to post data to a REST API that I'm building using Mongoose, Express and Node.js to postman.

My schema looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const BookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    isbn: String,
    tag: [String],
    genre: [String]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Books', BookSchema)
```

I am trying to add the book Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows to the DB through Postman like this:

```
{
    "title": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows",
    "author": "J.K. Rowling",
    "isbn": "9780545010221",
    "tag": [
        "England", 
        "Wizards", 
        "Schools", 
        "Magic"
    ],
    "genre": [
        "Fantasy",
        "Young Adult",
        "Fiction",
        "Adventure"
    ]
}
```

However, the output is:

```
{
    "tag": [],
    "genre": [
        "Fantasy",
        "Young Adult",
        "Fiction",
        "Adventure"
    ],
    "_id": "5ec5832ddc24ba3dc291c586",
    "title": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows",
    "author": "J.K. Rowling",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I don't understand why the **tag** array is empty, even though it is written exactly like the genre array.

Any ideas why?

**Update**

My code wasn't wrong, I was just missing topic (and isbn) to the enpoint object.

Comment: Can you show your endpoint code, on the one which you are making request through on postman?

Comment: @ShivamSood it's a localhost

Comment: I know it's localhost, but what's the code for endpoint because looking at the info you provided nothing seems wrong. So there should be something wrong with endpoint code.

Comment: Thanks for getting me to check, I had topic (and isbn) missing from my endpoint Book object.

Comment: @NonnaVee You also need to add the new keyword while defining a schema